# UTF-8 Encoding in JSP & Tomcat

Tags: jsp, http, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I am working in jsp based application running on tomcat 7.0.50

The jsp are saved in utf-8 and every jsp has

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I configured Tomcat connectors encoding to UTF-8

```
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

In the bin/catalina.bat, I added the param:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

But when I try to check the passed params in the http post from the form, i found that "Français" is passed as "FranÃ§ais".

How to resolve this and force the http post encoding to utf-8?
What is wrong with the config I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue, before dealing with the request paramters, just insert:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

And every thing will be ok

[Link where I found the solution](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q4)